# How can I find the next "available" time slot Interval from a duration?

Tags: datetime, jodatime, intervals, date-range

I have a list of `JodaTime` `Intervals`. These `Intervals` contain time specifications from:

(In military time)

```
00:00:00 - 10:00:00 
11:30:00 - 15:00:00 (3:00:00 PM)
15:30:00 - 23:59:59 (11:59:59 PM).
```

My issue is that I want to use `Interval` abstractions from the user to detect what time slot fits the user's desired interval.

For instance, with this code I calculate:

```
optimizeIntervals(generateMeetingIntervals());
generateBetweenIntervals();
ArrayList<Interval> during = getMeetingDuringIntervals();
ArrayList<Interval> between = getMeetingBetweenIntervals();
Interval desiredDuration = new Interval(now,now.plusMinutes(requestedDuration));

for(int i = 0; i<between.size();i++){
   Interval current = between.get(i);
   if(current.getEnd().isAfter(now)){
       if (current.contains(testing)){
           setNextAvailableStart(now);
           setNextAvailableEnd(current.getEnd());
       }
   }
}
```

However I cannot use `Interval`s as I need to find **the next available interval that fits the user's criteria.** If I use `Interval` for `desiredDuration` that means, if a user wants a timeslot that is "15 minutes long" I want the algorithm to find the **next available 15 minute time slot**. However, this algorithm does not work because intervals only check if the `start` and `end` times are between the containing interval's `start` and `end` times.

Example:

```
now = 10:30 AM
desiredDuration = 30 minutes
```

And `desiredDuration` is calculated as an interval from `10:30 AM to 11:00 AM`

loop runs:

is `10:30 AM to 11:00 AM` contained within `00:00:00 to 10:00:00`? - no

is `10:30 AM to 11:00 AM` contained within `11:30:00 to 15:00:00`? - no **should be yes**

However, on the second check I want to just see if there is a duration of `30 minutes` available within that time frame. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, you are using the wrong class; you want to use `Duration`. The question you are asking is: is there a 30 minute window available. You don't care when it starts, just "does it exist?" Therefore, use `Duration`, which has no concept of a start time or an end time.

Note that you are using `if(current.getEnd().isAfter(now))` *anyway* to answer whether the interval is after the current period.

So, check each period, generate a possible fit, make sure it's long enough, and then save it if it works. Here's some code:

```
Duration desiredDuration = new Duration(requestedDuration);

Interval validDuration = null;
for(int i = 0; i<between.size();i++) {
  Interval current = between.get(i);
  if(current.getEnd().isAfter(now)) {
    Interval candidateDuration = current.withDurationAfterStart(desiredDuration);
    if(current.contains(candidateDuration)) {
      validDuration = candidateDuration;
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Ha yea I just switched to duration and got it fixed!

Comment: I will write an answer with my implementation for people to view as well! Your answer works however too so I will accept it.

Answer (score 0):

As @durron597 has said, my issue was using `Interval` instead of `Duration`. Here is my implementation that works:

```
  this.meetingData = testMeetingData;
    availableNow = false;
    DateTime now = caseToTest;

    //Calculate range abstractions and optimize them.
    optimizeIntervals(generateMeetingIntervals());
    generateBetweenIntervals();
    ArrayList<Interval> during = getMeetingDuringIntervals();
    ArrayList<Interval> between = getMeetingBetweenIntervals();
    Interval testing = new Interval(now, now.plusMinutes(requestedDuration));


    if (testMeetingData.size()>0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < between.size(); i++) {
            Interval current = between.get(i);
            if (!current.getEnd().isBefore(now) && !current.getEnd().isEqual(now)) {
                if (current.toDuration().isLongerThan(testing.toDuration())) {
                    setNextAvailableStart(current.getStart());
                    setNextAvailableEnd(current.getEnd());
                    if (current.contains(testing)) {
                        setNextAvailableStart(now);
                        setAvailableNow(true);
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else{
        setNextAvailableStart(new DateTime().withTimeAtStartOfDay());
        setNextAvailableEnd(new DateTime().withTime(23,59,59,999));
        setAvailableNow(true);
    }
```